# Customized text on SIM pin unlock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, sim-unlocking

It happens to me occasionally to forget phone somewhere, usually when working on the field, so I have custom text displayed on LOCK SCREEN " If you find me, please call ". And it is super efficient, usually people call that number even before I realize I forgot phone.

But this only works when phone SIM is unlocked. If phone gets out of juice and powers off, when powering on SIM unlock prompt will pop up.

So, before I give laser engraved emergency number to back of casing, I am wondering if some customized message could be written on SIM unlock screen?